# loops not repeating in aegisub?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, lua

This is a code im working on in lua for an aegisub automation, the intended goal is to have it concatenate the first and second dialogue lines, then repeat that process until line 1 contains at least 55 characters, before moving on to dialogue line two, concatenating it with line 3 until line two is at least 55 characters, etc, etc.

in actuality when executed it will concatenate lines 1 and 2, deleting line 2 in the process provided line one is less than 55 characters, but after the single join it stops running. executing it repeatedly will continue to merge the 2nd line into the first until it hits the character threshold, at which point it will start merging line 2 with line 3, etc etc. this is almost exactly how I want it to function however I cant figure out why my loops dont cause the program to execute until all of the lines of dialogue fit the conditions.

ive tried changing `while ((l.class == "dialogue") and string.len(l.text) < 55 and i < #subs) do`
to
`while true do if ((l.class == "dialogue") and string.len(l.text) < 55 and i < #subs) then`

as well as attempting to add else statements to the end but these just return errors. I feel like it is a syntax problem with the way I've written my loops but im not super experienced with lua and am unsure

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
script_name="Concatenate lines"
scipt_author="andrew salazar"
script_description="Concatenates Lines under 55 characters"
script_version = "1"
 
include("utils.lua")
include("karaskel.lua")
 

function main_func(subs, sel, act)
    for i= 1,#subs do 
        l = subs[i]
        while ((l.class == "dialogue") and string.len(l.text) < 55 and i < #subs) do
            lines_to_delete = {}
            l_next = subs [i + 1]
            l.text = l.text .." ".. l_next.text
            l.end_time = l_next.end_time
            subs[i] = l
            table.insert(lines_to_delete,i+1)
            subs.delete(lines_to_delete)
            return lines_to_delete
        end
    end
end
 
aegisub.register_macro(script_name, script_description, main_func)
```

Comment: Why do you have `return` inside the loop?

Comment: when I move `return` outside of the first `end` the code no longer merges the dialogue lines or seem to have any effect at all in aegisub

Comment: Move it outside of the second `end`

Comment: moving the `return` outside of the second `end` spits this error out of aegisub

"

Lua reported a runtime error:
    File "X:/GMBN\experiment\Aegisub\automation\autoload\join.lua", line 12
<anonymous function at lines 10-23>
    File "<C function>", line -1
?
Requested out-of-range line from subtitle file: 73"

Comment: This means the loop works.  The new error is unrelated to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

had to use ipairs, now it works perfectly. thanks for the help!

```
script_name="Concatenate lines"
scipt_author="andrew salazar"
script_description="Concatenates Lines under 55 characters"
script_version = "1"
 
include("utils.lua")
include("karaskel.lua")
 
 
function main_func(subs, sel, act)
    for i, lines in ipairs(subs) do
        local l = subs[i]
            while ((l.class == "dialogue") and string.len(l.text) < 55 and i < #subs) do
                lines_to_delete = {}
                l_next = subs [i + 1]
                l.text = l.text .." ".. l_next.text
                l.end_time = l_next.end_time
                subs[i] = l
                table.insert(lines_to_delete,i+1)
                subs.delete(lines_to_delete)
        end
    end
    return
end
 
aegisub.register_macro(script_name, script_description, main_func)
```